# Como hacer una pregunta varias veces hasta que se cumpla PYTHON

Tags: python, vscode

Estoy desarrollando el juego de adivina quién de forma entendible y fácil para los usuarios y mi duda es cómo puedo hacer que, al momento de responder la pregunta de "Tu personaje tiene pelo negro?", si contesto que no me haga la pregunta con otro color hasta que diga que sí es de ese color y me lo agregue a mi lista PLAYER.

```
opc = str(input("EL color del cabello es negro? "))
    if opc == ("si") or opc == ("SI") or opc == ("Si"):
        player.append("Negro")

    if opc == ("no"):
        opc = str(input("Tiene el cabello castaño?")).lower()
    if opc == ("si"):
        player.append("Castaño")
    if opc == ("no"):
        opc = str(input("Tiene el cabello azul?")).lower()
    if opc == ("si"):
        player.append("Azul")
    if opc == ("no"):
        opc = str(input("Tiene el cabello gris?")).lower()
    if opc == ("Si"):
        player.append("Gris")
    if opc == ("no"):
        opc = str(input("Tiene el cabello rojo?")).lower()
        player.append("Rojo")
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es tu problema, pero sí veo que una manera de optimisar el código es colocar los nombres de los colores en una lista y luego ir iterando a través de ella.
Otro detalle es que no tienes en cuenta todas las posibles combinaciones de caracteres para "sí" y "no". Si lo entrado por el usuario lo conviertes en mayúsculas sólo tienes que comprobar si es "SÍ", "SI" y "NO", cualquier otra respuesta la puedes considerar no válida y volver a repetir la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando el código se torna repetitivo, es señal de que necesitas usar listas.

```
colores = ["negro"]

while True:
    for color in colores:
        opc = input(f"El color del cabello es {color} (si/no)? ").lower()
        if opc == "si":
            print("Que bien!")
            break
    else:
        colores.append(input("¿Que color es? ").lower())
```

Esta solución maneja una lista de colores conocidos, inicializada con el color negro a la partida:

```
colores = ["negro"]
```

Luego entramos en un ciclo infinito. En cada iteración hacemos una recorrida por la lista de colores preguntando:

```
while True:
    for color in colores:
        opc = input(f"El color del cabello es {color} (si/no)? ").lower()
```

La función `input` retorna un string; no es necesario aplicar `str()`. Lo que si es conveniente es pasar a minúsculas la respuesta, para simplificar su examen:

```
if opc == "si":
    print("Que bien!")
    break
```

Entonces, si el color existe, el `break` termina con el recorrido por los colores y vuelve a otro ciclo de adivinanzas.

Si el `for` recorre todos los colores sin encontrar el buscado, se ejecuta el `else:`, que se encarga de obtener el nuevo color y agregarlo a la lista.

```
else:
    colores.append(input("¿Que color es? ").lower())
```

#### Demo

```
colores = ["negro"]

while True:
    for color in colores:
        opc = input(f"El color del cabello es {color} (si/no)? ").lower()
        if opc == "si":
            print("Que bien!")
            break
    else:
        colores.append(input("¿Que color es? ").lower())
```

produce:

```
El color del cabello es negro (si/no)? SI
Que bien!
El color del cabello es negro (si/no)? no
¿Que color es? rubio
El color del cabello es negro (si/no)? no
El color del cabello es rubio (si/no)? NO
¿Que color es? gris
El color del cabello es negro (si/no)?
```